# CanActivate guard is not working properly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The issue what i am facing is when ever a class implementing CanActivate returns false (like after logging in the user is unauthorized view specific screen that time it return false, but after this when i request again for a autherized screen it doesn't make any request at all ). I am using observable request to backend to check a user is allowed to view a specific screen or not.

Comment: Without the relevant code, I doubt anyone will be able to help. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

That was a known issue, but was fixed 2 months ago https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13288

You should update to the newest Angular version.

Comment: sorry guy i didn't check the issue in Github, it is my mistake after upgrading the angular version it started working thank you.